# call different namespace or class from one in PHP

Tags: php, class, namespaces, autoload, bootstrapping

on `index.php` I have below code

```
require 'Bootstrap.php';
require 'Variables.php';

function __autoload($class){
    $class = str_replace('Control\\', '', $class);
    require_once 'class/'.$class.'.php';
}

$bootstratp = new Control\Bootstrap();
```

on `Bootstrap.php`

```
namespace Control;
class Bootstrap{
  function __construct(){
    Constructor::load_html();
    self::same_namespace_different_class();
  }
  static function same_namespace_different_class(){
    Variables::get_values();
  }
}
```

in `class/Constructor.php`

```
class Constructor{
  static function load_html(){
    echo 'html_loaded';
  }
  static function load_variables(){
     echo 'load variables';
  }
}
```

and on `Variables.php`

```
namespace Control;
class Variables{
    static function get_values(){
        Constructor::load_variables();
    }
}
```

Assume, In total I have 4 PHP files including 3 Class files of 2 different namespaces. I also have a `__autoload` function on `index.php` that will call classes from 'class' folder but my 'Control' namespace files are in root folder.

When I echo the class name in `__autoload` i get the all the class names starting with '`Control\`' even when I am calling a class from global namespace.

I am getting below error

```
Warning: require_once(class/Variables.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in _____________ on line 10
```

what is wrong with my code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I echo the class name in __autoload i get the all the class names starting with 'Control\' even when I am calling a class from global namespace.

This is because in `Bootstrap.php` all the code is in `Control` namespace (`namespace Control`). So when you use:

```
Variables::get_values();
```

you call

```
\Control\Variables::get_values();
```

if you want to use `Variables` from global namespace you should use here:

```
\Variables::get_values();
```

Of course, the same happens for in `Variables.php` file:

```
Constructor::load_variables();
```

As Constructor is defined in global namespace (in `class/Constructor.php` there is no namespace used), you should access it here using:

```
\Constructor::load_variables();
```

If it's still unclear you could also look at this question about [namespaces in PHP.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607045/difference-between-obj-new-arrayobject-obj-new-arrayobject)

You should also notice that using `__autoload` is not recommended. You should use `spl_autoload_register()` now. [Documentation about autoloading](http://php.net//manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: Marcin, Thanks a lot, That was great and fast,

Comment: Is there a way to call the global namespace without adding line `$class = str_replace('Control\\', '', $class);` in autoloader function.

Comment: @yellowandred In fact you should leave your autoload function unchanged - only `require_once 'class/'.$class.'.php';` should be there and in other classes you should use `\` at the beginning before class name if you want to use class from global namespace as I showed you in answer. You shouldn't remove namespace from class if class is in global namespace in autoloader because if you have classes in different namespaces it will cause serious problem. It would be also bad practice to do that.