# how to access to laravel global Classes in packages

Tags: laravel, package

I am developing a Laravel package . In the packeges I need to File::delete for delete files, but The following error message is displayed :

> Class 'Chee\Image\File' not found

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare it in the top of your class:

```
namespace Chee\Image;

use File;

class Whatever()
{

}
```

Instead of using the File Facade, you can also get it directly from the Laravel IoC container:

```
$app = app();

$app['files']->delete($path)
```

In a service provider, you can inject it as a dependency your package class:

```
class Provider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['myclass'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new MyClass($app['files']);
        });
    }

}
```

And receive it in your class:

```
class MyClass {

    private $fileSystem;

    public function __construcy($fileSystem)
    {
        $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
    }

    public function doWhatever($file)
    {
        $this->fileSystem->delete($file)
    } 

}
```

Comment: Tanks, Can I use servise provider for it? In this case, can you give me information?

Comment: Edited to provide more information on how to use it directly from the IoC and in a service provider.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro Why `use File;` is enough? `File` facade is in `Illuminate\Support\Facades` namespace so I don't know why it's working

Comment: Because you have an alias for it in your ´app/config/app.php´, Laravel instantiates all those classes during boot.

Comment: I use service provider and it worked correctly, Tanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use:

```
\File
```

Namespaces are relative to the namespace you declare for the class you are writing. Adding a "\" in front of a call to a class is saying that we want to look for this class in the root namespace which is just "\". The Laravel File class can be accessed this way because it is an alias that has an declared in the root namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have file something like that:

```
<?php

namespace Chee\Image;

class YourClass 
{
   public function method() {
     File::delete('path');
   }
}
```

you should add `use` directive:

```
<?php

namespace Chee\Image;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class YourClass 
{
   public function method() {
     File::delete('path');
   }
}
```

Otherwise if you don't use PHP is looking for `File` class in your current namespace so it is looking for `Chee\Image\File`. You could look at [How to use objects from other namespaces and how to import namespaces in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607045/difference-between-obj-new-arrayobject-obj-new-arrayobject) if you want