# Namespacing and autoloading in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

This might be a simple question but I'm wondering how do I autoload useful classes without declaring use statements on every single file.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        Input::get('query');
    }
}
```

If I remove the **use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;** line I will get a class not found error because I'm using the Input class.

Is there a way to autoload useful classes like Input, Response, View like in Laravel 4.  What's the point of the Aliases in app.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not really in Laravel, but in PHP. When you namespace a class, it assumes that everything inside that class will be in the same namespace, so you have to tell it that, for a particular class, you need it to use a different namespace.

You can use them by referring to the root namespace, like this:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        \Input::get('query');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot about using the blackslash for root.  Now it makes sense with the aliases in app.config

Answer (score 2):

You can import input class using both:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

or

```
use Input;
```

then you can use `Input::get('query');` code. That's how PHP namespaces work - you can also look at [How to use objects from other namespaces and how to import namespaces in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607045/difference-between-obj-new-arrayobject-obj-new-arrayobject/) for more details about it.

If you don't use `use` statement for importing class, you can use `\Input::get('query');` or `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('query');`.

Aliases allow you not to use fully qualified classes for example `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input` but shorter form `\Input`. That's why I showed above 2 versions - the shorter one uses aliases and the longer uses full class path. The same mechanism is both in Laravel 4 and Laravel 5 I believe.