# using function in name space without back-slash

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I'm working on Laravel framework, I have created a class under controllers/admin/PlacesController.php

I'm placing it in a name space controller/admin;

But as you can see below I can't use standart Laravel classes without "\" 
Please see \View

```
class PlacesController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $places=\Place::all();

        return \View::make('admin.places.index',compact('places'));
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return \View::make('admin.places.createOrEdit');
    }
}
```

But I would want to use it as View without "\" how can I do this? It is really a problem to fix all View to \View

Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should import `View` class because it's in other namespace (root namespace).

Add:

```
use View;
```

at the beginning of your file, for example:

```
<?php

namespace yournamespacehere;

use View;
```

Now you will be able to use in your controllers `return View` instead of `return \View`

If you want more explanation you could look at [How to use objects from other namespaces and how to import namespaces in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607045/how-to-use-objects-from-other-namespaces-and-how-to-import-namespaces-in-php)