# Laravel Alias not finding class

Tags: php, class, laravel, alias, autoloader

I am trying to register an Alias to a class, but Laravel can't find the class, i can reference the class directly in my controller, so i know its loaded correctly.

here is my code:

```php
    'aliases' => array(
        'FrontendAssets' => 'Lib\FrontendAssets',
    )
```

the class I am trying to make an alias for

```php
class FrontendAssets{

    protected static $styles = [];
    protected static $scripts = [];

    public static function styles(){
        return static::assets(static::$styles);
    }

    public static function addStyle($style){
        static::$styles[] = $style;
    }

    public static function scripts(){
        $scripts = static::assets(static::$scripts);
        return $scripts;
    }

    public static function addScript($script){
        static::$scripts[] = $script;
    }

    public static function assets($assets){
        return array_map(function ($asset){
                return $asset;
        }, array_unique($assets));
    }
}
```

This is what i am trying to call in my controller

```php
FrontendAssets::assets();
```

I have tried adding namespaces but still no joy.

If i use `\FrontendAssets::assets();`
in my controller, I can use the class so I know it is defiantly been loaded

Answer (score 17):

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Might help also. In case you have previously cached config files with `config:cache` since aliases are defined in app config.

Comment: This is it! Cache needed to be cleared for Laravel to detect the new aliases! :D

Answer (score 15):

First run `composer dump-autoload` to make sure the class can be found.

Now, when you have controller in namespace, for example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class YourController {

}
```

if you want to access `FrontendAssets` class you need to add leading backslash, so `FrontendAssets::assets();` won't work but `\FrontendAssets::assets();` will work.

You can alternatively import this class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use FrontendAssets;

class YourController {

}
```

and now you will be able to use `FrontendAssets::assets();`. If it's unclear you might want to look also for explanation at [How to use objects from other namespaces and how to import namespaces in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607045/how-to-use-objects-from-other-namespaces-and-how-to-import-namespaces-in-php/24607087#24607087)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I cleared cache but I missed \ in front of class and it won't work. Up!

Comment: I like the alternative approach anyway so I don't have to add \, but that extra line, but that is okay.

Answer (score 1):

You need to empty cache and dump the autoloads, you can do it **with a single command**:

```
composer dump && php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel caches the configuration to avoid runtime loading overhead. You have to run one of the given artisan commands.

Below given command will clear out the configurations cached previously.

```
php artisan config:clear
```

And the below given command will clear and re-cache the configuration.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

After clearing the configuration cache, you will be able to use that alias defined in `config/app.php`.