# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found and I also cannot use a new Model

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, models, laravel-5

I have very basic problem. In L4 thes below methods worked out of the box, so now I am lost. Please help. A few days ago I started a Laravel 5.0 project. I have now fresh, clean installation.

Problem 1: When I try to get anything from database

```
$headquote = DB::table('quotation_texts')->find(176);
```

I get this:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found
```

Problem 2: Before I cloned the User.php Model, changed Class name to "Quotation". Below is the content of file Quotations.php put in App root folder:

```
<?php namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Quotation extends Model  {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'quotation_texts';
}
```

Any attempt to use the model

```
$headquote = Quotation::find(176);
```

ends up with this:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Quotation' not found
```

Any ideas how I could resolve the issue?

Comment: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The problem here are PHP namespaces. You need to learn how to use them. As your controller are in `App\Http\Controllers` namespace, if you refer any other class, you need to add leading backslash (or proper namespace) or add `use` statement at the beginning of file (before class definition).

So in your case you could use:

```
$headquote = \DB::table('quotation_texts')->find(176);
$headquote = \App\Quotation::find(176);
```

or add in your controller class `use` statement so the beginning of your controller class could look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use App\Quotation;
```

For more information about namespaces you could look at [How to use objects from other namespaces and how to import namespaces in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607045/how-to-use-objects-from-other-namespaces-and-how-to-import-namespaces-in-php/24607087) or [namespaces in PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php)

Comment: Thank you!  Dziękuję!! 
I cannot vote up as my reputation is not high enough, sorry for that!

Comment: The solution worked only with DB.

With my model, the situation now is this: 
if I put use Quotation; in the controller or put backslash in quoery
$headquote = \Quotation::find(176);
I get this: Class 'Quotation' not found

Before I got 
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Quotation' not found
Which suggests that the L% is recognizing 'Quotation' as name for a controller.

Comment: @PiotrPlebaniak As your `Quotation` is probably in `App` namespace, I've edited my answer

Comment: Now it works, but only as the use **App\Quotation;** variant. 

It doesn't work in the query command - syntax error, unexpected '/'

Comment: @PiotrPlebaniak And where do you have `/` in here? It should be `\`

Comment: The real question is... Why? Why no tutorial told me about that and I needed to find it myself? About the \ thing.

Comment: @dawn This is how namespaces work in PHP. I've added link at the end of my answer to other resources

Answer (score 15):

Quick and dirty

```
use DB;
```

OR

```
\DB::table...
```

Answer (score 7):

Just add this top of your controller.

```
use DB;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the backslash before db on the header and you can use it then typically as you wrote it before.

Here is the example:

```
Use \DB;
```

Then inside your controller class you can use as you did before,  like that ie  :

```
$item = DB::table('items')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    use DB;

    class UserController extends Controller
    {

    function  index(){

    $users = DB::table('users')->get();

    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        var_dump($user->name);
    }

    }
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in name spacing as in laravel 5.2.3

```
use DB;
use App\ApiModel; OR  use App\name of model; 

DB::table('tbl_users')->insert($users); 

OR

DB::table('table name')->insert($users);



model 

class ApiModel extends Model
    {

        protected $table='tbl_users';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this witch i think is cleaner :

1 - Add the model to namespace:

```
use App\Employee;
```

2 - then you can do :

```
$employees = Employee::get();
```

or maybe somthing like this:

```
$employee = Employee::where('name', 'John')->first();
```