# how to use include_once() with namespace in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

I am new in laravel and importing a existing php site.
I created a controller named "List" then i need to create a object of a class, coded in a file which is been include by include_once() as shown,

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


$INCLUDE_ROOT = 'path/to/file';
include_once($INCLUDE_ROOT . "ServiceDetails.class.php");

class Lists extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        $objServiceDetails= new ServiceDetails;
        .........
        ........
     }
 }
```

But i am getting an error like

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\ServiceDetails' not found

I dont have much idea of namespace "use" and "as".
May be that's why i am not able to solve this problem.
When creating a new object it is searching class in namespace location only, but it should also look in included files, i think.

Comment: yeah, but you're in a namespace (imagine it being a folder), so ServiceDetails is in the "current folder" (App\Http\Controllers). Try using `new \ServiceDetails`, or the full namespace of that class if it has one

Comment: @DamienPirsy , Thanx buddy, it works when i used `new \ServiceDetails` but its a huge project so in a controller lots of files include , and many time object are being created, is any other way to end the scope of namespace, so that we can create object normally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's a namespace in current file, PHP will try to find class in current namespace and if it won't find it, you'll get fatal error. You should open `ServiceDetails.class.php` class to verify if there is `namespace ...;` at the beginning of the file (after `<?php`). If not you can simple add in your `Lists` file after:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

the following line:

```
use ServiceDetails
```

and if it is, you should copy that namespace and add the following line:

```
use namespaceyoucopied\ServiceDetails;
```

of course in `namespaceyoucopied` place you need to put the correct copied namespace so it could look like this:

```
use A\B\C\ServiceDetails;
```

You can also look at [How to use objects from other namespaces and how to import namespaces in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607045/how-to-use-objects-from-other-namespaces-and-how-to-import-namespaces-in-php/24607087#24607087) or [PHP namespaces manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a `use` statement for that class so the class in the current file can "see" it.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

$INCLUDE_ROOT = 'path/to/file';
include_once($INCLUDE_ROOT . "ServiceDetails.class.php");

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Namespace\To\ServiceDetails;

class Lists extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        $objServiceDetails= new ServiceDetails;
        .........
        ........
     }
 }
```

However, if you are using Laravel and doing this, then you are not using the autoloading feature to its fullest.  I recommend you put this file in a namespaced directory in your application and have it follow [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).  Then Laravel will load this for you, and it will keep your class file looking clean.

Put the file in a path like the following: `/path/to/projectRoot/app/Lib/ServiceDetails.php`.  Then make the file look like below so it follows PSR-4:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Lib\ServiceDetails;

class Lists extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        $objServiceDetails= new ServiceDetails;
        .........
        ........
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanx i think it's standard but actually its a huge app so there is lots of file being include and many objects are being created, so its tough to change every include() to namespace.