# How to create sqlite file in Laravel 5.2 framework?

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, namespaces, laravel-5

I want to create an Sqlite file manually whenever user registered. I use

```
new SQLite3($file_path)
```

But Laravel keep tell me

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Sqlite3' not found
```

Please help me with this. Thank very very much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
new \SQLite3($file_path)
```

or put

```
use SqlLite3;
```

below

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Now you are trying to use `SqLite3` from current namespace.

You might be also interested in looking at [How to use objects from other namespaces and how to import namespaces in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607045/how-to-use-objects-from-other-namespaces-and-how-to-import-namespaces-in-php)