# Laravel 5.4 - Paginate from array collection products

Tags: php, pagination, namespaces, laravel-5.4

i'm trying to paginate a collection's products, like this:

```
$products_array = array();

        for ($i=0; $i < count($t); $i++) { 

            $p = Product::where('category_id',$t[$i]->category_default)->where('project_id',$t[$i]->id)->first();
            array_push($products_array, $p);
        }

        $paginate = new Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($products_array, count($products_array), 10, 1, ['path'=>url('api/products')]);

        dd($paginate);
```

But i get this error:

> FatalThrowableError in HomeController.php line 75: Class
>   'Shop\Http\Controllers\Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator' not
>   found

i don't know if this is the best way to do this, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Try to use backslash before Illuminate become new \Illuminate\Pagina...

Comment: @SuryaDarmaPutra return this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/'

Comment: How is your code look like now? Have you check which piece of code contains '/', because I suggest you to add backslash ('\') not slash. Maybe there's some error in the other line of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is really self explaining. You are trying to use `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` from current namespace and this is `Shop\Http\Controllers`.

To fix this, either add leading backslash like so:

```
$paginate = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($products_array, count($products_array), 10, 1, ['path'=>url('api/products')]);
```

or at the beginning of this PHP file (after opening PHP tag) add new line:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
```

and then you can write above line like so:

```
$paginate = new LengthAwarePaginator($products_array, count($products_array), 10, 1, ['path'=>url('api/products')]);
```

To read more about namespace in PHP you can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24607087/3593996

Comment: i think currentpage = null not 1
before $paginate = new LengthAwarePaginator($products_array, count($products_array), 10, 1, ['path'=>url('api/products')]);
after  $paginate = new LengthAwarePaginator($products_array, count($products_array), 10, null, ['path'=>url('api/products')]);